# Get a List of Reactions on a Message discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to get a list of reactions on a discord message and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code.

```
async def reactionGetter(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('Message to put reactions on')
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(msg.reactions)
```

The code successfully adds the reaction, but it prints out an empty list. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This appens because `msg = await ctx.send('Message to put reactions on')` is temporary, it's not the message in the bot's cached messages. You can only get reactions of cached messages so, in your case `msg.reactions` will return a blank list.
Also, you were using, `time.sleep(5)`, which is wrong, it would stop your entire program for 5 seconds. With asynchronous functions, you'd have to import `asyncio` and use `asyncio.sleep()`.

You'd have to change your function to:

```py
from asyncio import sleep

async def reactionGetter(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('Message to put reactions on')
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
    await sleep(2)
    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(bot.cached_messages, id=msg.id) #or client.messages depending on your variable
    print(cache_msg.reactions)
```

**Reference:** [No reactions in Message.reactions](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/861#issuecomment-338355516)

Comment: Thanks, this was useful! I'm still having an issue with this method. Either 'Client' object has no attribute 'messages' or 'Bot' object has no attribute 'messages'.
I have my bot and client as follows;
```bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()
me = discord.ClientUser
```
msg.channel.fetch_message method is working, but I'm always curious to find more ways to solve a problem

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it should be `bot.cached_messages` ^^'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextChannel.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message), which will force your bot to get the message information from Discord via an API call, instead of relying on Discord to update your client via websocket.

```
async def reactionGetter(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('Message to put reactions on')
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
    msg = await msg.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)  # Can be None if msg was deleted
    print(msg.reactions)
```