# Discord.py ticket system

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have started making Ticket bot using discord.py but I have an error in my code and I don't know how to solve it. Embed and reacting to  message work but when I try to react everythings crashes. Here is my error:

```
Ignoring exception in command ticket:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\222\dscbot-dscbot.py", line 150, in ticket
    if reaction == '':
NameError: name 'reaction' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'reaction' is not defined
```

I hope someone have and idea how to fix this, here is my current code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import Embed, Color
import DiscordUtils
import os
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import json




intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-", intents = intents)
client.remove_command("help")




@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ticket(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Ticket system',
        description = 'React  to make a ticket.',
        color = 0
    )

    embed.set_footer(text="ticket system")

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    reaction = await msg.fetch_message(msg.id)


    await client.wait_for("reaction_add")



    await client.wait_for("reaction_add")

    if reaction == '':
        await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {reaction.author.name}')
```

ps: I am new to discord.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reaction = await msg.fetch_message(msg.id)` is just giving you `msg`. You instead need to take the reaction from `await client.wait_for("reaction_add")`

Take a look at [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for). You implement a check (Which is where the reaction is) to see if the reaction is a mailbox.

You  need to create a new function that creates a channel if the reaction is a mailbox, then pass that into `client.wait_for`.

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return str(reaction) == '' and ctx.author == user

await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {ctx.author}')
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? As I said I am new to dsc.py and I know only basics.

Comment: @MatanKa. I added the finished product to my answer

Comment: ```File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\222\dscbot-dscbot.py", line 151
    await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {reaction.author.name}')
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\222> ``` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MatanKa. Sorry, I messed up. I edited the answer and everything should be good to go now!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `reaction`, that's why this error is raised.
Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972542/12203337) to find out how to fetch reactions from messages.

Comment: I dont know if I did this well but this time I got:   ```Ignoring exception in command ticket:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\222\dscbot-dscbot.py", line 145, in ticket
    reaction = await msg.fetch_message(msg.id)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'```

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the changes you have made?